# Magento 1.9.1.0 Front-end login error

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

On Magento 1.9.1.0, when a new user registers, registration completes and new user is sent to their customer panel. When user logs out and tries to log back in, Magento gives this error: `Error Message: User name or password is incorrect`

On Magento version 1.9.0.1, this problem does not exist.

Any ideas?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Multiple reason can cause that problem. With which browser did you tried ? Did you tried with another one ? Are you in a local environment and trying to access the Magento with 127.0.0.1 ? Have you changed the URL of this Magento recently ? And finally which OS is your server ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something with the activation (double opt-in)?

You should provide screenshots of the different user-states in the backend, directly after registering, after clicking the activation-link in the email, after login, after login, after re-login and so on.